# ios Swift: How can I record audio without speaker's voice?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, record

I have a requirement that I need to record user's voice with built-in microphone when I simultaneously play a rtmp stream with player.

I use vlcplayer to play rtmp stream. And I have tried to record in two ways. One is use AudioEngine. Another one is AVAudioRecorder.

I'm facing problems on each way.

If I use AudioEngine, the vlcplayer will be no sound. If I use AVAudioRecorder it will record user's input with the vlcplayer's output voices with built-in speaker.

How can I record audio without speaker's voice?